# Script to copy collection of folders into subfolders seperated in parts

Tags: windows, copy

I have a collection of files sizing up to 33+GB ,

There are 415 folders of these files.

```
CD0001
CD0002
CD0003
CD0004
CD0005
CD0006
etc, etc...
```

These are updated files/folders to a program that gets new updates every quarter, and its been racking up as you probably can tell.

We have them seperated in parts 1-27 , to divide them in about 800-1,5GB parts.
(started with about 1GB per part)

What I am hoping someone can help me create is a script that I can run, that will Copy the CD* folders, to their respective Parts folder, without me having to go into the folder every time and check that they are there.

ie.

```
See folder C:\temp\updates\CD0001  
Looks for CD0001 in all parts folders (example \\\server1\program\part*\\*)  
Removes Old CD* folder.  
Copies in New CD* folder.
```

When I started with the parts, there were gaps inbetween the CD's, as in there were CD0001-CD0255 and then CD0330-CD0880, etc.

And a few quarters later, they release CD0280, CD0281, CD0282, etc and they are too big.

So I needed to make a Part28 and then the continuance gets broken... :)

Its a SVN system aswell, so I cant move CD's from part2 to part3.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266270/specific-warnings-to-newbies-about-homework-code-writing-please-debug-and-sscce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles upon this,

Made a quick one where I could have made the list better, but...

```
$Source = "<SourcePath>"

$Part01 = "Destination_Part01"
$Part02 = "Destination_Part02"
$Part03 = "Destination_Part03"
$Part04 = "Destination_Part04"
$Part05 = "Destination_Part05"
$Part06 = "Destination_Part06"
$Part07 = "Destination_Part07"
$Part08 = "Destination_Part08"
$Part09 = "Destination_Part09"
$Part10 = "Destination_Part10"
$Part11 = "Destination_Part11"
$Part12 = "Destination_Part12"
$Part13 = "Destination_Part13"
$Part14 = "Destination_Part14"
$Part15 = "Destination_Part15"
$Part16 = "Destination_Part16"
$Part17 = "Destination_Part17"
$Part18 = "Destination_Part18"
$Part19 = "Destination_Part19"
$Part20 = "Destination_Part20"
$Part21 = "Destination_Part21"
$Part22 = "Destination_Part22"
$Part23 = "Destination_Part23"
$Part24 = "Destination_Part24"
$Part25 = "Destination_Part25"
$Part26 = "Destination_Part26"
$Part27 = "Destination_Part27"

$PartList ($Part01,$Part02,$Part03,$Part04,$Part05,$Part06,$Part07,$Part08,$Part09,$Part10,$Part11,$Part12,$Part13,$Part14,$Part15,$Part16,$Part17,$Part18,$Part19,$Part20,$Part21,$Part22,$Part23,$Part24,$Part25,$Part26,$Part27)

ForEach ($Item in $PartList) {
$CDList = get-childitem -Directory -name $item
$PartPath = $item
ForEach ($Item in $CDList) {
    If (Test-Path "$PartPath\$Item") {
        If (Test-Path "$Source\$Item") {
            Write-Host "Replace is True"
            Write-host "Copying $Source\$Item to $PartPath\$Item"
            Robocopy "$Source\$Item" "$PartPath\$Item" /E /Purge /NP /TEE /FFT /R:1 /W:1 /Log:"C:\temp\Logs\$Item.log"
            write-host "$Source\$Item Processed"
            move-Item -Path "$Source\$Item" "$Source\Processed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```